# Getting validation error webp image upload

Tags: 8, media

I have added a image field to my "Blog" content type. In image field settings 'Allowed file extensions' section include webp format.

When I upload webp format image gerring below validation error. Am I missing somthing?

"The selected file hair-treatment-spotlight.webp cannot be uploaded. Only files with the following extensions are allowed: png, gif, jpg, jpeg."

Comment: WebP should be supported starting with Drupal v9.2, see https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2340699 (note that your hosting provider must support this too, Drupal can not work with webp if the server's image toolkit is not up to date)

Comment: Thanks @Hudri for quick reply. Shared link is really helpful. I have applied the patch & worked for me.